# Is there a way to access the label text in a UIView?

Tags: text, uiview, interface-builder, label

When I add a view in Interface Builder, I often go into the Identity Inspector, scroll down to the "Document" section, and edit the "Label" field. This makes it easier to tell one view from another in the "Objects' browser. But I was wondering: Is there a way to access that text from the controller for my view?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot.

But if you want to access something about UIView in both code and Interface Builder, you can set TAG value as property of UIView.

This is usefully for me in debugging process.